# Difference in POST call with Flask Security

Tags: jquery, python, ajax

I don't understand why I have a difference between two API (POST) calls.
I have one call with python requests and one call from the navigator (with jquery ajax).

The python requests call works well.

```
>>> r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/login', data=json.dumps({'email':'myemail@gmail.com', 'password':'password'}), headers={'content-type': 'application/json'})
>>> r.json()

{'meta': {'code': 200}, 'response': {'user': {'id': '1', 'authentication_token': 'WyIxIiwiMjM2MmNhMGJlN2M5ZTZlOGFjNDdmNWQ0ODEzM2U2MjAiXQ.C4Umjw.k62yqWcmxW-si5hHN4qi6auMm2g'}}}
```

However, the Jquery call is redirecting me to the `/login` html page.

```
$.ajax({
   url: '/login', 
   dataType: "json",
   method: "POST",
   data: {'email':'myemail@gmail.com', 'password':'password'},
   success: function (response) {
      console.log(response.data);
      _this.setToken(response.data.token);
   },
   error: function (err) {
      console.log(err);
   }
});
```

How can I make the Ajax call works like the python requests?

Comment: Can you show us your server side code that handles /login and /dummy-data URLs, please.

Comment: @Hannu sorry, both point to `/login`, the default api of flask-security.

Comment: What is your response.data or error message after the Ajax call?   A couple of ideas to try:  1) Insert contentType: "application/json" to your Ajax call as you send this in the python request.   2) You might need to use $.ajaxSetup({ beforeSend: function(xhr,settings) ..... })   to insert csrftoken. http://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/csrf.html  explains the structure and you can pretty much copypaste from there.